# Incrementally building a list without memory overhead

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a task, where I have to combine pairs with a function, but the number of pairs I actually need is much smaller than the number of all pairs. The condition to keep the element is some function of both elements. Originally, I used something like:

```
Select[Flatten@Outer[function,array1,array2],condition]
```

However, this creates a huge computational and memory overhead: it generates the entire matrix (which is quickly bigger than RAM, and also takes time to apply function when I'll just throw it away), and then also takes time to filter.

I was looking for a non-procedural way to do this, and it seems most builtins are oriented towards constructing everything and filtering later. `Map` is out of the question, so are `Table` and `Array`: Even leaving Nulls in the array is an overhead, and using Sequence appeared worse. I ended up writing

```
ApplyIf[f_, a_, b_, condition_] := 
  Module[{result = {}, n1 = Length[a], n2 = Length[b], i, j},
   For[i = 1, i < n1, i++,
    For[j = 1, j < n2, j++,
     r1 = a[[i]];
     r2 = b[[j]];
     If[condition[r1, r2],
      AppendTo[result, f[r1, r2]];
      ]
     ]
    ];
   result
   ];
```

which does solve the memory overhead problem, but being procedural, it's not in the spirit of Mathematica, and I'm also concerned with time complexity of `AppendTo`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Is `Reap` / `Sow` advisable in these situations?

Comment: "the number of pairs I actually need is much smaller than the number of all pairs" -- have you thought about `SparseArray` to reduce memory usage?

Comment: @Stitch I still have to go over all pairs to figure out which ones I need.

Comment: [Forget about `For` for good](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12) and use `Sow`/`Reap` with `Do`.

Comment: I often hit the memory limits of my kernels, crashing them. And effective trick I use to avoid both the time complexity of `AppendTo` and procedural programming is to simply chunk my arrays. Alternatively, `Reap` and `Sow` will indeed circumvent the time complexity of `AppendTo` and by using a `Do` loop instead of your `For` loops you can remove the time complexity from all those `For` tests and incrementations and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you, I quite forgot about `Do`, it also avoids a double loop, much cleaner.

Comment: Alternatively, you could give us an idea of what `condition` is (i.e. explain what you are trying to do), and perhaps we could come up with a functional way of doing what you want to do. That said, the `Sow`-`Reap` construction is a good one, and I use it a lot.

Comment: I agree with @Szabolcs `For` should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Not only does it avoid a double loop, it also avoids explicit indexing.  Instead of `Do[f[array[[i]]], {i, Length[array]}]` you can use `Do[f[elem], {elem, array}]`.  All this will effectively save you the `Module`, as you will not need local variables anymore.  `Reap@Do[If[condition[r1, r2], Sow@f[r1, r2]], {r1, a}, {r2, b}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs just write it as an answer for me to accept, it works beautifully.